# For request with mode=no-cors, even if the response contains access-control-allow-origin, is the response still opaque?

Tags: javascript, cors, service-worker, httpresponse

For request with mode=no-cors, even if the response contains access-control-allow-origin, and the origin of the request is in the list, is the response still opaque?

And how can you tell if the response is opaque by looking at the network tab? I know if I use a service worker to intercept the request and refetch, then I can look at the response type or status to determine if it's opaque, but network tab doesn't seem to show whether the response is opaque or not

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.